# Load entire html (with doctype) in jQuery object | Prevent iFrame from loading scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to load an entire `HTML` via `AJAX` and then manipulate the `DOM` with `jQuery`. This means the retrieved `HTML` does include a `doctype` and other top level elements.

Getting the `HTML` is easy:

```
$.get('/my/url', function(html) {
  //full html loaded.
});
```

But here comes the tricky part: If you simple load the `html` in a `jQuery` object like var `$obj = $(html)`, it won't work. A lot of information will be stripped because it would load it like you entered the following: (notice the double `doctype`)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
      <div>
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Different browser will handle this differently, as also explained in [jQuery load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) documentation, in the `Loading Page Fragments` section.

> jQuery uses the browser's .innerHTML property to parse the retrieved
>   document and insert it into the current document. During this process,
>   browsers often filter elements from the document such as `html`,
>   `title`, or `head` elements. As a result, the elements retrieved by
>   .load() may not be exactly the same as if the document were retrieved
>   directly by the browser.

I solved this issue by loading the `html` via an `iframe` like below:

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
//iframe.setAttribute("sandbox", "");
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(iframe);
iframe.onload= function() {
  var doc = iframe.contentWindow.document;
  var $html = $(doc);
};

iframe.contentWindow.document.open();
iframe.contentWindow.document.write(html);
iframe.contentWindow.document.close();
```

This works, as `$html` now has the complete `DOM` including headers and title. But since I basically load the entire `HTML` in an `iframe`, the browser will start to parse it and it also loads all `javascript`, `stylesheets`, `images`, etc. losing the point of the `ajax` load in the first place, to prevent loading content I already have. (Yeah, i know about caching, but that`s not what I'm after here)

To prevent the loading I tried to enable `sandbox` on the `iframe`, but this also disables access to it from a static domain that hosts the `script` that takes care of all this.

So the question is: How can I load the entire `HTML` in a `jQuery object`, without loading all the referenced scripts and images in the `HTML`

Comment: Have you tried _not_ appending the iframe to the current document?

Comment: @CBroe: Yes, then you get `Cannot read property 'document' of null`

Comment: If you use the [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method you can target the body tag or whatever; just put a space and the jQuery selector after the load url, like `$(selectorYouLoadTo).load('url.php body')`. Keep in mind you can only have one HTML id attribute value per page, though.

Comment: @PHPglue perhaps if you read the entire question, You'll find why `load()` is not an option.

Comment: You can load portions of the other page. Did a magic wand write your code for you before?

Comment: Instead of an iframe, load the whole thing as text, and then feed that into a new DOMParser maybe …? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser Not sure if that would have the same issue of loading external resources “automatically” though. // (But if you need to load the complete document anyway, then I’m wondering how much sense AJAX still makes here to begin with? A good old plain link still has its right to exist sometimes ... :)

Comment: @CBroe I don't need the entire content.Headers, footers, menu all stay on the site after load. But my designer wants a smooth transition of the main content (like fadeOut old content, replace with new content, fadeIn new content) to give an app like feeling. This does work great, but I dont like seeing my browser trying to load all scripts and images again. Even though technically they all return 304. But since I also need the `title` tag for example to change the page title after I push the new stte, I can't use `load()`

Comment: Caching is configured properly, but the cache is returned after the browser tries to load the content. So your network tab still shows a lot of request, regardless if there is a lot of network action. Since the contents of the iframe is parsed, all reflows are created, javascripts , etc is being executed. It's just a lot of extra things the browser is doing that isn't needed. Using `load()` is not an option because of the problems address in their own documentation and besides that, I need multiple parts of the same page. Load handles one part.

Comment: @CBroe the DOMParser was the key, thank you. If you add it as an answer, i'll award the credits. Just the basics is enough, i'll update it with working solution if you like.

Comment: Sure, happy to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of an iframe, you could try and load the whole second document as text, and then feed that into a new DOMParser. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser

That should give you access to all parts of the document (head, body, what-have-ya.)

(Not sure if you might need to use `document.importNode` then to get nodes to properly import into your main document, that might depend on what method exactly you are using to do so.)

Answer (score 1):

So, basically you're trying to implement page transition without the page-load.
[PJAX](https://github.com/MoOx/pjax) is exactly what you need.

From it's README:

> It allow you to completely transform user experience of standard websites (server side generated or static ones) to make them feel they browse an app. Especially for user that have low bandwidth connection.
>
> No more full page reload. No more lots of HTTP request.

There is also a [jquery-based plugin](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax), but it's deprecated now. The [pjax](https://github.com/MoOx/pjax) library is the only thing you need.

Comment: I guess I did rebuild `pjax`, but since it's finished I wont be needing an external plugin. Thanks for the link though. But I have seen other plugins that do this, most of them didnt support different actions on different links, which is what I need. Not sure if this one does support it.

Answer (score 0):

Working solution thanks to @CBroe:

```
function loadDom(html)  {
  if (typeof window.DOMParser != "undefined") {
      var dom = new window.DOMParser().parseFromString(html, "text/html");
      if (dom) {
        var $html = $(dom);
        console.log('dom loaded');
        handlePageObject($html);
        return;
      }
  }

  /*
  create iframe to store the received html
  since the HTML is an entire page including doctype and <html> we can not use it directly in a jquery object
  */
  var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(iframe);
  iframe.onload= function() {
    console.log('loaded from iFrame');
    var doc = iframe.contentWindow.document;
    var $html = $(doc);
    iframe.remove();
    handlePageObject($html);
    return;
  };
  iframe.contentWindow.document.open();
  iframe.contentWindow.document.write(html);
  iframe.contentWindow.document.close();
}

function handlePageObject($html) {
  //do something with entire html as jquery object
  var title = $html.find('title').html();
  console.log(title);
}
```